# Use CHTTP and CHTTPParser in same Swift Project

Tags: swift, linker, vapor, swift-package-manager

i created a [Swift library](https://github.com/cpageler93/CVServiceRegistry) which uses [Kitura-Net](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-net) which uses [CHTTPParser](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-net/blob/5b1b9b2463633f43f0e9fcee74c8360d6feb8d81/Package%40swift-4.0.swift#L30).

Now i'm trying to use my Library inside a [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) application which uses [CHTTP](https://github.com/vapor/engine/blob/decf702d774ac630dfe0441ff76b4bb68257b77a/Package%40swift-4.swift#L7).

My library builds perfectly fine and my Vapor application **without my library** builds fine also.

But when i add my library as a dependency, so it compiles inside the Vapor application i get **duplicate symbols** errors.

It seems like both CHTTP and CHTTPParser implemented the same class: **http_parser**

Here is my log after a clean build:

```
Compile CHTTP http_parser.c
Compile CSQLite sqlite3.c
Compile CHTTPParser utils.c
Compile CHTTPParser http_parser.c
Compile Swift Module 'libc' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Debugging' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Bits' (19 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'PathIndexable' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SwiftyJSON' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Socket' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'LoggerAPI' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Core' (23 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Random' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Transport' (10 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Node' (38 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Console' (35 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Crypto' (13 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'BCrypt' (9 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'URI' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Sockets' (22 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Cache' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Branches' (3 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'JSON' (9 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SQLite' (4 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'TLS' (12 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SMTP' (21 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Configs' (13 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Fluent' (70 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'SSLService' (1 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'HTTP' (45 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'KituraNet' (36 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Cookies' (11 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'WebSockets' (14 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Multipart' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Sessions' (7 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Routing' (10 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Quack' (4 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'FormData' (4 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Vapor' (97 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'ConsulSwift' (17 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Testing' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'FluentProvider' (19 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'CVServiceRegistry' (2 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'App' (5 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Run' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/Run
duplicate symbol _http_parser_settings_init in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_init in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_url_init in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_method_str in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_errno_description in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_version in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_parse_url in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_body_is_final in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_message_needs_eof in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_should_keep_alive in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_execute in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_pause in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_errno_name in:
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTP.build/http_parser.c.o
    /path_on_my_mac/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: terminated(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /path_on_my_mac/.build/debug.yaml main
```

Does anyone has a solution for me to solve this problem?

Interesting Information: When I build and run the Vapor Application with Xcode, everything works fine.